# IBM Bluemix demo from GitHub, node.js cloudant sample, "Deploy to IBM cloud" button fails with unable to find repo

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use the bluemix demo from GitHub, node.js cloudant sample (https://github.com/ibmecod/nodejs-cloudant).

When I click the "Deploy to IBM cloud" button in the README to create the toolchain in bluemix, I get the following error in IBM Cloud

```
Template Error
Repository not found.
Github repo not found: https://github.com/ibmecod/nodejs-cloudant
```

Not sure what is going on, that URL is fine if I paste it into my browser.
t

Comment: There is an issue with the toolchain in some regions. Depending on your account, could you add `&env_id=ibm:yp:eu-gb` to the URL to use the UK environment?

Comment: Thanks, yes adding that to the URL worked and created the app in the UK region.

Comment: Should work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a temporary problem in one of the regions.

A solution can be to switch to another region where the open toolchain is available.

Answer (score 0):

The **Create Toolchain** works again for the Demo.

[image: Deploy to Bluemix]

Here was the issue which is now resolved:

https://console.bluemix.net/status/notification/e9a442353742c249572c49226c5208f5

You can view the status of the IBM Cloud here:

https://console.bluemix.net/status